# Separate jackson feature from classes

Tags: java, jackson

I am using jackson to handle JSON (de)-serialization. I have a bunch of classes which are annotated with are essentially objects holding properties and associated getters and setters.

However, I often find that at some point I want to add additional properties which I don't want to include in the (de)-serialization process. This does work using `@JsonIgnore`, but it strikes me as relatively ugly since I have to add the annotation everywhere and things break down as soon as I forget.

I would like to know if there is a better way to separate the ignored and serialized properties. I have the following two ideas:

- Use inheritance, add the *new* properties to the inherited `class`:

  ```
    // everything here should be (de)-serialized
    class Base {
      public int getJSONProperty() {...}
    }

    // nothing specific to the class Derived should be (de)-serialized
    class Derived extends Base {
      // *not* to be included
      public SomeClass getAdditionalProperty() {...}
    }
  ```

  However, I don't know how to tell jackson to deserialize the `Derived`
  objects as `Base`s. Is this possible (Does jackson make guarantees
  regarding (non)-polymorphic serialization of classes)?
- Use [MixIn annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotationshttp://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations). This would require an additional abstract
  class for each existing class. Also I am not sure whether this solves
  the problem. Are getters which do not appear in the MixIn base class
  ignored automatically or do I need to `@JsonIgnore` them manually?

Comment: What about `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)`? This will effectively deserialize only properties which exists in class with json annotations `@JsonProperty`. In your case if class member value `private SomeClass additionalProperty` doesn't have `@JsonProperty("additionalProperty")` annotation it shouldn't be serialized at all.

Comment: Well, I would like to have the different properties in different locations (aka files) as well... Apart from that, I guess it would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen that you don't like the previous solution i've provided, so I'm again here to provide another way to do what you want using Gson Library. I hope to help you this time.

This is The Base Class that you want to serialize

```
public class Base {
    public int getJSONProperty() {
        return jsonProperty;
    }
    private int jsonProperty = 2;
}
```

This is The Derived Class that you don't want to serialize

```
public class Derived extends Base{
    public String getAdditionalProperty(){
        return additionalProperty;
    }
    private String additionalProperty = "value-not-to-serialize";
}
```

Using `Type type = new TypeToken<Base>(){}.getType();` you can define the class to use for serialization so you get the JSON String using:

```
Derived derived = new Derived();

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Base>(){}.getType();

String jsonString = gson.toJson(derived, type);
```

Answer (score -2):

You know Gson? it's a good library to handle JSON.

You can use transient keyword to define variable thats not must be serialized, this works with Gson (It should work well with jackson, but i'm not sure)...

```
class Base {
    // (de)-serialized
    private int jsonProperty;
    // not (de)-serialized
    private transient SomeClass additionalProperty;
}
```

I think the best approach is to add annotation or use the transient variable. 
Create the inheritance only for the purpose of serialization an object complicates the application uselessly in my point of view...

Comment: Can you please explain me what's wrong? Thanks in advance